# Create a Sqlite Database in C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

Is it possible to create a Sqlite database file using C++?
I've googled this to death and can't find a thing.
I can only create Sqlite tables using C++.

Thanks.

Comment: It is of course possible. sqlite is a c api so is fully accessible from c++.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [reference](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html):

> `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` | `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`
>      The database is opened for reading and writing, and is created if it does >not already exist. This is the behavior that is always used for `sqlite3_open()` and `sqlite3_open16()`.

So if you are using `sqlite3_open` this is automatic; if you are using `sqlite3_open_v2` you have to include those flags.

Comment: Thanks for that.. Perfect answer..

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite3_open()` will create the database for you, if the file does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm)

You can see an introduction of Sqlite C/C++ interface [here](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks,, I just found a tute and have just caught on. It's on the below link as well.http://hayageek.com/ios-sqlite-tutorial-create-select/